# how can I find good shapefile of Leeds (UK)?

Tags: metadata, tableau-api, geospatial, spatial, shapefile

I was trying to find a shapefile of Leeds (UK) and use it in Tableau, I found one on CDRC Data website, but it doesn't have any area names and not very satisfying.

Can anyone tell me where I could find nice shapefile. Many thanks.

Comment: VTC as off-topic, but this belongs on the [OpenData stack](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/). There was no option to choose that stack in the flag.

Comment: @Andy Oh sorry, new to StackOverflow, but thanks a lot.